# input checkbox always returns 0 in POST

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am trying to use checkboxes in a html form and send them to the my sql database by post. but i always get 0 no matter the checkbox is ckecked or not.

this is html form :

```
   <form action = "MediaList2.php" method = "POST">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="gradea" value="1"> CPC for Grade A websites<br><input type='hidden' value='0' name='gradea'></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="gradeb" value="1"> CPC for Grade B websites<br><input type='hidden' value='0' name='gradeb'></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="gradec" value="1"> CPC for Grade C websites<br><input type='hidden' value='0' name='gradec'></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="clicksno" placeholder="if you want a specific number for your clicks please mention it here ">Number of Clicks<br></li>
        <li> Duration<input type="text" name="start_date" class="form-control" id="start_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" /> <span> TO </span>  <input type="text" name="end_date" class="form-control" id="end_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
 </li>
        <li> Budget <input type ="text" name ="budget" required></li>

             <button type= "submit">Submit</button> 
             </form>
```

this is my php code:

```
    try{
   // receiving the post params
    $gradea= $_POST['gradea'];
    $gradeb= $_POST['gradeb'];
    $gradec= $_POST['gradec'];
    $clicksno= $_POST['clicksno'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    $budget = $_POST['budget'];
    if($budget > $_SESSION['totalcampaignbudget'])
    {
               echo "Your CPC budget should not be bigger than your total budget!";
               exit(0);
    }
    $user = $db->storeinCPC($gradea , $gradeb, $gradec, $clicksno, $start_date, $end_date, $budget, $campaignname, $email);
```

and this is my storinCPC function in php:

```
public function storeinCPC($gradea , $gradeb, $gradec, $clicksno, $start_date, $end_date, $budget, $campaignname, $email)
    {                                                                            // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                                                                                      // Check connection
                                                                                       if ($conn->connect_error)
                                                                                       {
                                                                                       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                                                                       }                                                                             
    $q1 = "SELECT * from CPC where tocampaign = '$campaignname' AND toperson = '$email' " ;
    $res1 = $conn -> query($q1);
    $count = $res1 ->num_rows;
    if($count != null )
    {
        $query = "UPDATE CPC set clicksno ='$clicksno' , GradeA = '$gradea', GradeB='$gradeb', GradeC = '$gradec',budget='$budget', tocampaign='$campaignname', startdate='$start_date', enddate='$end_date', toperson='$email', updated_at = NOW()  WHERE   toperson = '$email' AND tocampaign = '$campaignname'";
    }
    else if($count ==0)
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO CPC (clicksno , GradeA, GradeB, GradeC,budget, tocampaign, startdate, enddate, toperson, created_at, updated_at ) VALUES ('$clicksno', '$gradea', '$gradeb' , '$gradec', '$budget', '$campaignname', '$start_date', '$end_date', '$email', NOW(), NOW())";
    }
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection. You really should fix that. Use prepared statements and bound parameters for all user-supplied data.

Comment: why are you having  <input type='hidden' value='0' name='gradea'> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a single of those input lines gives a clear understanding of your main issue:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="gradea" value="1"> CPC for Grade A websites<br><input type='hidden' value='0' name='gradea'></li>
```

Do you notice that you created a checkbox input field with name `gradea`, and right after created a hidden input field of the same name with `value='0'` which overwrites the first one?

Comment: I added hidden value so that the checkbox sends a value even when it is unchecked! how am i suppose to do that if this way is wrong?

Comment: Something along the lines of: `$gradea = isset($_POST['gradea']);` will make `$gradea` a boolean. Or if you want 1 or 0, `$gradea = isset($_POST['gradea']) ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: You should put the hidden input before the checkbox. Whenever the checkbox is checked, it's value will override your hidden input's value when submitted, otherwise the hidden value will be submitted instead.

Comment: @user3259983  awesome!